# remove characters from all cells in column according to a limit

Tags: excel, limit, office365

i have an excel file with a column, that some of its cells exceed my system limit.
some cells in this column, even have 10000 characters.

i need a way to cut all cells in the column to 2000.
read all solutions in the site but all of them use formulas which are not good enough because my system will not understand formulas when the file is imported into it.

**i need to actually cut the text in the cells,** delete it! not create another cell with formula that only shows the result of the formula.

Can i do that in excel? (office365)

Answer (score 0):

**This will impose a limit on the cell rather than delete it hope that helps.**

> Step 1: Select the range that you will limit date entries with specify
>   character length.
>
> Step 2: Click the Data validation in the Data Tools group under Data
>   tab.
>
> Step 3: In the Data Validation dialog box, select the Text Length item
>   from the Allow: drop down box. See the following screen shot:
>
> Step 4: In the Data: drop down box, you will get a lot of choices and
>   select one
>
> Step 4: Entry exact number that you want to limit in
>   Maximum/Minimum/Length box according to your needs.
>
> Step 5: Click OK.

Comment: Sorry but It doesn't work, it just warn about the exceeded limit, but it doesn't cut the actual text. i also created an empty column with the above limit you suggested and copied the original column to the limited column. it doesn't cut  the text. it just warn that the cell is exceeding when i edit a cell.

Comment: You could try make it in to a pivot table and do it but that might be to much messing around.